# \n for NSString not work for string from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c

I retrieve `NSData` from a server containing `\n`. When I convert it into an `NSString`, `\n` is not working. It prints "\n".

My code is like this:

```
 NSString *st=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data];
```

Thanks

Comment: `%s` is for `char *`

Comment: It really depends how you are viewing `st`.  If it's in the debugger then that's different from writing it to file and reading it...  Tell us how you are viewing the value.

Comment: You could split the string on @"\n" an check the count of the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
NSString * string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:yourData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: my data also contain ; maybe it cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

That may help you.

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
```

Comment: my data also contain ; maybe it cause the problem